# Method Type Inference in the Java Specification

Tags: java, compiler-construction, type-inference, specifications

I am currently writing a Java compiler and have implemented section 15.12.2.7. of the JLS7 (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7) , one of the most annoying sections of the spec. I still have one problem since the spec somehow seems underspecified or ambiguous. My problem is this line:

*lcta(U) = ? if U's upper bound is Object, otherwise ? extends lub(U,Object)*

U is an arbitrary type expression. What is the upper bound of a type expression? In addition, why is the lcta always a wildcard?

The spec defines

*CandidateInvocation(G) = lci(Inv(G))*.

Now, for example, consider the case that Inv(G) = { List<String> }, i.e., the only possible candidate invocation is a single parameterized type. Now, due to the rule

*lci(G<X1, ..., Xn>) = G<lcta(X1), ..., lcta(Xn)>*,

the result of CandidateInvocation( G ) =
lci( { List<String> } ) would be defined as:

List<lcta(String)>

in my opinion, lcta should simply return String here, because if List<String> is the only possible invocation, it is a good idea to infer List<String> as the argument. However, the definition of lcta(U) dictates that the result is either ? or ? extends lub(...), so the result IS ALWAYS a wildcard. This seems strange. What am I misinterpreting here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have asked in the compiler-dev mailing list and received the answer:

Yes, the specification is wrong here. The rule for lcta(U) is simply total crap :). In addition, they claimed that it would be even better to not call lcta(U) at all for a single argument and just use U (since the least common type argument of a single argument U should always be U itself).

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a bug of the spec. The clause of `lcta(U)` didn't exist in JSL3. Apparently JLS3's definition of `lci(e1..en)` is incomplete when `n=1`, and the new spec tries to fix it. But the fix seems gibberish, as you reasoned.

Javac7 calculates `lci( { List<String> } )` as `List<String>`, ignoring the added clauses.

This problem should be raised to spec maintainers; not sure how to contact them. You could try openjdk *compiler-dev* mailing list; there are some knowledgeable people on it.

Comment: I have now implemented lcta(U) = U which seems to work fine. I will report if I find any cases where this implementation produces surprising results. By the way: Isn't lub(U,Object) always U, since Object is always a super class of U and thus the minimized erased candidate MEC of {U, Object} should always yield U or one of its subclasses? Thus, the rule is really complete crap. The only thing which it might be good for is transforming ? extends Object to ?. However, since U is a type expression, it cannot contain wildcards so this case may never arise... really strange.

Comment: and good idea with the mailing list, I think I will try it there

Comment: lub = least upper bound. I think any type should be lower,i.e.,"less", than object. Otherwise, the call of lub(U,Object) would be even more moronic since it could simply be replaced by Object.